# Need a value prompt to select multiple items and use wildcard

Tags: cognos

I have this filter currently setup on my query and it works
[Replenishment Code] contains ?vendor?

However i need to replace "contains" with "in" to get multi select working in my value prompt

BUT, i am not able to add a wildcard to the "in" operator like so
[Replenishment Code] in ?vendor? + '%'

Is there any way to do this?

My replenishment code is setup like this
AIPRODU-WA
AIPRODU-SF
etc...

But i had to substring ?vendor? to everything before the "-". so you see
AIPRODU

Answer (score 0):

Use a prompt macro function to generate a filter of 
vendor like #prompt(sq('vendor','string') + '%'#
Macro functions allow you to change text of query before it's sent to datasource, it's quite flexible
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r1m0/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.10.1.0.doc/ug_cr_rptstd_id51759mac_prompt.html#mac_prompt

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this [Replenishment Code] = #prompt(sq('vendor','string') + '%'# BUT i get an error parsing. But doesn't multi select in value prompt on let you use "in" operator?

Comment: I mistyped the whole thing, sorry. Should be  [Replenishment Code] = #sq(prompt('vendor','string','123') + '%')#. If this works, you can use the promptmany function and change the condition to in instead of =